# Converting a factor variable in a data variable

Tags: r, date

I have large data set with 10 billion rows. In this large data file there is a date variable. But this variable is factor in nature (e.g. 19MAR2012, 20FEB2012 etc). I want to convert this factor variable in original data variable. I have tried in this way, but its showing "NA" output! Could anybody please suggest me the possible solution using R?

```
 strDates <- c("19MAR2012")
 dates <- as.Date(strDates, "%d %m %Y") 
 dates
 #[1] NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
as.Date(strDates, "%d%B%Y") 
#[1] "2012-03-19"
```

Please check the documentation at `?strptime` to know different formats.

---

Or you could also do

```
library(lubridate)
dmy(strDates)
#[1] "2012-03-19"
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is `anydate` from `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
anydate(strDates)
#[1] "2012-03-19"
```